# Does the friend XP Boost in Fortnite stack with how many players you have?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Part of the battle pass rewards for Fornite include "10% friend XP boost". If I have 3 friends that have this, will I gain 30% more xp?

Or would it be applied 10%, 10%, 10% and increase it by more?

How do the friend XP boosts in Fortnite stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XP boost is combined. So if you have 3 friends. 1 has 20%, 1 40% and 1 has 10%

It will be added together and give you a 70% boost.